Why is $\Bbb N$ $\not \subseteq \{\Bbb N\}$?
I am working through Hammack's Book of Proof to self-study proofs. This is also my first exposure to basic set theory. Example 1.6 lists 20 statements, all of which make sense to me except for one: $\Bbb N$$\not \subseteq \{\Bbb N\}$. The reason given is "because, for instance, $1\in\Bbb N$ but $1 \not\in \{\Bbb N\}$". I don't understand this because $\Bbb N$ contains $1$, so why doesn't the set of $\Bbb N$ also contain $1$?
I understand this is a very basic question, but I don't want to continue further in the book until I thoroughly understand each section.

Subsets of ${ \mathbb{N} }$ are sets themselves. Think: $\mathbb{N}$ is a box, and the previous is a box containing that box.

Since $x \in \left{ y \right} \iff x = y$ for any $x$ and $y$, $1 \ne \mathbb{N}$ implies $1 \notin \left{ \mathbb{N} \right}$.

One little thing that may help: a subset of a set can't have 'more' elements than the set itself does (I'm being deliberately fuzzy here, but there is a true statement behind this). Now $\mathbb{N}$ has infinitely many elements, but ${\mathbb{N}}$ has only one...

The only element of {$\mathbb N$} is the set $\mathbb N$ , nothing else , in particular not the elements of the set $\mathbb N$

Try to avoid the c word;  it is too ambiguous to be helpful to your intuition. Instead of thinking "$\mathbb N$ contains $1$", think "$1$ is an element of $\mathbb N$". It should then become clear that "$1$ is not an element of ${\mathbb N}$".

$\{\mathbb{N}\}$ has only one element called $\mathbb{N}$.
Something like $\{\{1,2,3,4,5\}\}$. Can you claim $1\in \{\{1,2,3,4,5\}\}=A$?
No, since the set A has only one element called $\{1,2,3,4,5\}$.
